# How to use Powershell to refresh all Microsoft Edge tabs?

Tags: windows, powershell, microsoft-edge

I am trying to set up Edge tabs to rotate and refresh at selected intervals. Rotate every 20 seconds, refresh every 1 hour. I have found some Powershell online which I have amended to be able to rotate all open tabs like below:

```
while(1 -eq 1){
$wshell=New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('Microsoft Edge'); # Activate on Edge browser
Sleep 20; # Interval (in seconds) between switch 
$wshell.SendKeys('^{PGDN}'); # Ctrl + Page Down keyboard shortcut to switch tab
}
```

The above works perfectly for rotating tabs. However, I also want to be able to refresh all tabs every hour. Is there any way I can amend the above to refresh all tabs after an hour, or maybe set refresh schedule up on a different Powershell script?

Cheers for all help

Edit 16/07/2019 - I amended PS to below:

```
while(1 -eq 1){
$wshell=New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('Microsoft Edge'); # Activate on Edge browser
Sleep 20; # Interval (in seconds) between switch 
$wshell.SendKeys('^{PGDN}'); # Ctrl + Page Up keyboard shortcut to switch tab
Sleep 1; # Interval (in seconds) between switch 
$wshell.SendKeys('{F5}'); # F5 to refresh active page
}
```

This does refresh each tab but not according to my needs. I need to rotate every tab after 20 seconds, but refresh every tab after 1 hour. Any way I can amend this PS to achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
$wshell.SendKeys('{F5}');
```

Comment: How would I add this into my existing PS, to rotate each tab every 20 seconds, but refresh all tabs every hour? I cant get that working correctly

Answer (score 0):

I try to test it with MS Edge and it seems that we cannot refresh all the tabs using the Powershell Script. If we are using "$wshell.SendKeys('{F5}');", it will just refresh the current active page, instead of all of the tabs.

I will try to submit the feedback regarding this issue. If I get any solution or a work around then I will try to provide you in the future. Thanks for your understanding.